Click listener prevents click from registering
I added this simple event listener (in the context of content.js of my browser extension)
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.altKey) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}, true,)

This works fine in 90% of the elements I clicked. That means the click registers in the element and if I hold Alt it also logs the event into the console.
However, some buttons on some websites behave differently. Here the click registers when I don't hold down the key but it does not register if I do.
Example button: The color choices for nike shoes (https://www.nike.com/t/air-max-dn-shoes-27XkSQ)
I tried to register the listener on window load and also tried to set useCapture = false.
So my question is, why does that happen and is there a way to solve this?
Thanks a lot!

@wOxxOm interesting, but sadly didn't resolve the issue. Let me check the run_at

Are the elements where this event handler does not work loaded after the DOM is ready? If so you need to use a delegated event handler, or a MutationHandler to detect when they've been added. The best approach would depend on the specific use case


Remove document. or replace it with window., which is the first target in the first phase of event dispatch that your listener uses by supplying true in the third parameter.

Use mousedown in addition to click. It's dispatched earlier.

Add "run_at":"document_start" to content_scripts declaration in manifest.json so your listener is registered earlier than the site's one.
Note that there's no head or body at that moment, only document.documentElement, so to wait for the contents of the page use MutationObserver or DOMContentLoaded listener.


Don't forget to reload the extension in chrome://extensions.
